# Extract string between characters

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to extract 2 arguments from given string using regex. For example:

> C:\Users "C:\Program files"
>
> C:\mytext.txt mytext2.txt

Output would be C:\Users and C:\Program files

C:\mytext.txt and mytext2.txt

If string is between *" "* it can contain white spaces, otherwise it has to be without them. So far I managed to extract arguments between *" "*, but can't figure out how to extract them when one argument has *" "* and the other one doesn't (like in example above).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|\\S+");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK6tS6/1)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!